# How to make itertools.product() random

Tags: python

I have the code below that will print all possible combination of 'abc'. Is there a way I can only print part of the combinations, or to make it print the combination randomly every time.

my code is:

```
from itertools import product
for item in product('abc', repeat=3):
  codes = (''.join(item))
  print(codes)
```

the result with this code gives me this :

```
aaa
aab
aac
aba
abb
abc
.
.
.
bcc
caa
cca
ccb
ccc
```

I want it the result to be random everytime or only print specific part like this:

```
bcc
caa
cca
ccb
ccc
```

Comment: What have you tried and not succeeded with so far?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably use something like:

```
from itertools import product
from random import choice

all_samples = ["".join(x) for x in product("abc", repeat=3)][0:10] # as requested on the comments, limits the list to the first 10 items.

def rand_sample():
    sample = choice(all_samples)
    all_samples.remove(sample)
    return sample

for _ in range(10):
    print(rand_sample())
```

---

```
cbc
caa
acb
bbc
abc
cac
aaa
ccb
aac
acc
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/1ab6429b96)

Comment: is there a way to make it only print a part of that for example just print first part : cbc
caa
acb
bbc
abc

Comment: I see that you never accepted a correct answer on [all your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11778890/secatt). It's polite and helps other users if you do so.

Comment: i thought repeat =x is to set how long each combination, what I need is for example print the first 10 combinations only

Comment: you can slice the list if needed,  `all_samples[0:10]`, then `sample = choice(all_samples)`

Comment: def rand_sample():
    all_samples[0:10]
    sample = choice(all_samples)
    all_samples.remove(sample)
    return sample

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212511/discussion-between-secatt-and-pedro-lobito).

Comment: I've updated the answer using `[0:10]`, change the number as needed.

Comment: refresh the page and check the demo

Comment: last question please, how do I do the same thing without the randomization? I just need to limit the list to  specific item without the def  `rand_sample():` function.

Comment: your method is working but  i run out of memory if i use this `all_samples = ["".join(x)for x in itertools.product("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", repeat=5)][0:10]
print(all_samples) `, I m assuming because it will try to create all the content of the list then just print the first 10. is there a way to solve this?

Comment: @secatt see my answer for this last question (but it's randomized)

Answer (score 0):

[The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61434410/7456923) works, but you have to create the whole product list, which can take excessive time and memory.

You can use function [`random_product`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.random_product) from `more_itertools` instead.

```py
from more_itertools import random_product
for _ in range(10):
    print(''.join(random_product('abc', repeat=3)))
```

Comment: This is fine, but it's sampling with replacement. It's also not an iterable, otherwise you'd care about the _ and not just use it as a placeholder. Also 10 is an arbitrary choice. What if you don't want to think about the size of the iterable?

Answer (score -2):

```
from itertools import product
from random import shuffle
list = product('abc', repeat=3))
shuffle(list)
```

Should do it.

Comment: A code dump with no explanation in response to a code request with no effort is not useful. You've also masked `list`.

Comment: I apologize for being a beginner, I m trying my best buddy.

Comment: @secatt That has nothing to do with being a beginner.